# Can I make the error handler for a backburner worker just kill the worker process

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a fleet of Backburner workers (`Backburner::Workers::Simple`). I seem to have hit an edge case where a worker occasionally can't get a DB connection, the job is reaped back by the server, and suddenly the worker goes on a tear, reserving jobs rapid-fire, all of which time out and eventually get buried, because the worker never again successfully gets a DB connection. Obviously, it would be ideal if I could fix the weirdness around DB connections and rapid-fire job reservation. That seems like a longer-term solution, though, because I've looked and don't see anything obvious. What I'd like to do is just have my error handler log the error, and then for the whole worker process to die. All of my workers are under process supervision, so this is a very clean, simple way to get a fresh worker without the DB problem. I've tried adding `; Kernel.exit` (and variations on that) to my `on_error` lambda, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. How do I make this happen?

Comment: have you tried getting the pid of the worker and then call the system with 
`system("kill -QUIT #{worker.pid}")`. as you said, it is not the best solution, it doesn't seems to be safe. But it have to work.

Comment: How would I get the pid? Are you suggesting I shell out to `ps` and grep through the output in that handler?

Comment: if I understand ok your question you have some tasks that are working bad after some errors, and you want to get the error, do some things and then kill the worker is that correct? if it is, you can get the error as normal, log what you need and then with a system, run a command to kill the worker with the pid.

Comment: looking at how to get the pid, I found this
`https://github.com/nesquena/backburner/blob/master/lib/backburner/workers/threads_on_fork.rb`

there is a kill_forks method that maybe can help you

Comment: @xploshioOn This was enough to eventually lead me to the solution for what I was asking (combining `Process.pid` w/ the `system` call you suggested). If you consolidate the advice into an answer, I'll accept it and award the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the need is to kill the worker completely, no matter what, you can make a call to command line from ruby with `system()` to run a `kill` command.

So you just need to get the PID of the worker and then kill it from system call

```
system("kill -QUIT #{worker.pid}")
```

looking at how to get the PID of the worker, I get [this information](https://github.com/nesquena/backburner/blob/master/lib/backburner/workers/threads_on_fork.rb) from backburner repository, and it seems like you can get the PID from the worker with

```
Process.pid
```